# Sign message with certificates in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, cryptography, blazor-webassembly, x509certificate2

I am using `Blazor WASM` with .NET6.
Given a `X509Certificate2` certificate I want to sign a message.

Looking at code I from another (desktop) project I have

```
private static string GenerateSecret(string timestamp, string deviceName, string challenge, X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    string message = timestamp + deviceName + challenge;
    byte[] originalData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

    var hashAlgorithm = HashAlgorithmName.SHA512;
    var rsaSignaturePadding = RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1;

    var hash = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey().SignData(originalData, hashAlgorithm, rsaSignaturePadding);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

But Visual Studio tells me both `RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1` and `certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey().SignData()` are not supported for my platform:

```
warning CA1416: This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'RSA.SignData(byte[], HashAlgorithmName, RSASignaturePadding)' is unsupported on: 'browser'.
```

Now my question is: Is it possible to sign a message in `Blazor WASM` or is this not possible at all in this context? What alternatives would I have for achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given a `X509Certificate2` certificate ... `wasm`

In addition to `RSA` not being supported, `X509Certificate2` is also not supported on wasm.  Either we don't have warnings enabled for X509Certificate2 in .NET 6, or you haven't included a constructor call in your code yet, but all of the constructors are [marked as `[UnsupportedOSPlatform("browser")]` in .NET 7](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/release/7.0/src/libraries/System.Security.Cryptography/ref/System.Security.Cryptography.cs#L2787-L2823).

In .NET 6 the only cryptographic concept with support in wasm is hashing.  In .NET 7 it will be hashing and HMAC.  There's no encryption or signing support, and nothing with certificates.

For "just RSA" you can look into doing interop directly with the [Subtle Crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) intrinsic API.  To my knowledge there's not a standard wasm notion of certificates.

Comment: That is too bad. Is there any way to do certificate authentication with `WASM`?